# ListGetAt function returns type conversion error

Tags: list, coldfusion

I have the following code:

```
<cfif SideSell neq "">
    <cftry>
        <cfif listlen(SideSell, ",") gt 0>
            <cfset sidesellvalid = true>
            <cfelse>
            <cfset sidesellvalid = false>
        </cfif>
        <cfcatch type="any">
            <cfset sidesellvalid = false>
        </cfcatch>
    </cftry>
    <cfif sidesellvalid>
        <cfset AddPartNumber = "">
        <cfset AddDescription = "">
        <cfset AddQuantity = "">
        <cfset AddPrice = "">
        <cfset OptionPrice = "">
        <cfset AddItem = "">
        <cfloop list="FORM.SideSell" index="SideSellListIndex" delimiters=",">
            <cfquery name="qSideSellParts" datasource="Pascal">
                SELECT * from Part WHERE PartNumber = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="yes" separator="," maxlength="45" value="#ListGetAt(SideSell, SideSellListIndex, ',')#">
            </cfquery>
            <cfset AddPartNumber = "#qSideSellParts.PartNumber#">
            <cfset AddDescription = "#qSideSellParts.SubCategory#">
            <cfset AddQuantity = "1">
            <cfset AddPrice = "#qSideSellParts.PartPrice1#">
            <cfset OptionPrice = "0">
            <cfset AddItem = "Add To Cart">

            <cfinclude template="checkpart.cfm">
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>
</cfif>
```

However, CF is throwing a typecasting exception, saying

> "The value FORM.SideSell cannot be converted to a number."

at the SQL line:

```
SELECT * from Part WHERE PartNumber = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="yes" separator="," maxlength="45" value="#ListGetAt(SideSell, SideSellListIndex, ',')#">
```

The test data I have tried includes "PTI 19-1" and "PTI 19-1,PTI 19-2" so the problem exists regardless of the list item count. Am I simply missing or misusing a quote mark?

EDIT: Running CF9 on my testing server, CF8 on production server. I used a `<cfdump>` tag to verify the data is what I expected, and it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how cfloop works with the list attribute - you don't need ListGetAt since the value is contained in the index.

(Technically this isn't accurate - it should be `item` because that's what you're getting, but whoever originally implemented cfloop did it this way and we've been stuck with it.)

Also note that list must be a string - not a variable name - so you need hashes to evaluate the variable to one.

Finally since you're looping through your list one item at a time, you should *not* use the list attribute of cfqueryparam - (this is for when you are doing `WHERE PartNumber IN (x,y,z)` style queries and want the parameter treated as multiple values.)

In summary, your loop should look like this.

```
<cfloop list=#Form.SideSell# index="PartNumber">
    <cfquery name="qSideSellParts" datasource="Pascal">
        SELECT * from Part
        WHERE PartNumber = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#PartNumber#">
    </cfquery>
    ...
</cfloop>
```

(If you don't understand why, add a comment and I'll try to explain further.)

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot the value was contained in the index variable. And I agree, it **should** be `item`, not `index`! However, the error message is misleading; shouldn't CF be complaining about the SideSellListIndex variable?

Comment: It was complaining about the SideSellListIndex variable - because of the missing hashes on the list attribute, the value of that variable was the string "FORM.SideSell", which is what the error was reporting as not being numeric.

Comment: _Also note that list must be a string - not a variable name - so you need hashes to evaluate the variable to one._ Totally missed this somehow. If that is the case, then why does the CF8 documentation state: **Atttribute:** List **Description** "A list, variable, or filename; contains a list." ?

Comment: Good question. Don't know why it says that, but it's wrong. The list attribute accepts a string value (or an expression that results in one), and does not convert the string to a variable name or file name.

Comment: That section is trying to explain three different types of loops at once (list, array and file). Looks like they just messed up.